# What's the difference between (reader.ready()) and using a for loop to read through a file?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

In my previous question, I asked about a problem with looping through a file, and solved it. However, I realised that the method failed to read the last set of lines/record. So I changed the original `for` loop to a `while(reader.ready())`. So:

**Original `for` loop:**

```
     int numberOfLines = readLines();
     numberOfLines = numberOfLines / 6;

     for(int i=0;i < numberOfLines; i++)
```

**Changed that to:**

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.dat"));

while(reader.ready())
```

What's the difference between the two, and a little more specifically, what exactly does the `.ready()` do?

Comment: What type is your "reader" variable? I've never seen this type of animal before.

Comment: edited it, correctly I hope..

Comment: What does the javadoc say? What don't you understand in it?

Comment: I'm not really sure there's much of a point to `ready()` to begin with - if you need to do what it's meant to do, you probably want to use NIO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

> Tells whether this stream is ready to be read. A buffered character stream is ready if the buffer is not empty, or if the underlying character stream is ready.
>
> **Returns:**
>   True if the next [read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()) is guaranteed not to block for input, false otherwise. Note that returning false does not guarantee that the next read will block.

So, the buffer will be `ready` if `read` is guaranteed not to block.

As JB Nizet [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325652/whats-the-difference-between-reader-ready-and-using-a-for-loop-to-read-thro#comment21640420_15325815), this does *not necessarily mean that you have reached the end of the file*. If, for any reason, your stream *might* block, then `ready` will return `false`.

Instead, try reading your files like this:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    // code code code
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Read the javadoc of ready(). It doesn't mean there's something to read. It means that the next read is guaranteed not to block. It's not equivalent at all to the "other way", which is the right way to read a file line by line.

Comment: JB Nizet beat me to answering why downvote

Comment: Well, if `read` would block for input, then that means the end of the file has been reached, right? So if it's guaranteed not to block, doesn't that mean that it would have to return something immediately; i.e., there *is* something to read?

Comment: No. If the end of file has been reached, `readLine()` will return null. `ready()` will return false if there's still something to read, but reading could block.

Comment: How could there still be something to read at the end of the file? (thanks for bearing with me)

Comment: I never said that. What I said is that if you stop reading when ready() returns false, then you won't read the whole stream, because ready() returning false does NOT indicate EOF. It indicates that the next read() could block.

Comment: @WChargin now that you've learnt why.. I will remove the downvote with the slightest modification in the answer :-)

Comment: Same for my downvote.