# Buffered Socket Reader doesn't wait for data from remote connection

Tags: java, io

I have a Java program that reads data from a TCP source all works fine, except when my program (which acts as a client to the data source) is faster then then the source can respond BufferedReader.ready() throws an exception that closes my TCP connection, as it should. Is there any preferred way/method that I can keep the BufferedReader waiting for new input since my source can sometimes have a slight delay.

Here is the part that i am talking about:

```
 public aDataServer(String host, int port, StreamConnection aConnection) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
            this.aConnection = aConnection;
            ndataServerSocket = new Socket(Inet4Address.getByName(host),port);
            ndataServerReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ndataServerSocket.getInputStream()));
        }


 public void run() {
            try {
                RemoteDevice dev = RemoteDevice.getRemoteDevice(aConnection);
                OutputStream outputStream = aConnection.openOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                do {
                    try {
                        String ndata = ndataServerReader.readLine();


                          osw.write(ndata+"\n");
                          osw.flush();
                          LOG.log(Level.INFO,"Sent");


                    } catch(IOException io) {
                        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Client device({0}) disconnected: \n{1}", new Object[]{dev.getFriendlyName(true), io.getMessage()});
                        break;
                    } 
                }while(ndataServerReader.ready());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                LOG.severe(ioe.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (ndataServerSocket != null) {
                                ndataServerSocket.close();
                    }
                     if (ndataServerReader
                             != null) {
                                ndataServerReader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the exception that gets thrown?  Can you include a code snippet of how you're constructing and reading from the BufferedReader?

Comment: updated my questions with some code

Comment: Can you post the exception output as well?

Comment: maybe exception is the wrong word I thought because the code falls into the lines of  `}while(ndataServerReader.ready());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {`
I get an exception from `ndataServerReader.ready()` that triggers the .close()

Comment: When you run this, and it fails, what do you see output?  You said "BufferedReader.ready() throws an exception".  Sharing error message/stack trace/exception/anything can help diagnose what is causing the error.  Also, your code snippet doesn't show how you construct `ndataServerReader`, which may very well be relevant.

Comment: updated with the constructor. I do not get an output no, the program just disconnects from the source because there is no data coming for the moment. Which I think is what it is suposed to do, but desired is that it stays open and waits for new data as the source can have a delay sometimes.

Comment: I can play with the timing of how fast the source can deliver data for test purposes. If I deliver too slowly the java program quits the connection if i deliver too fast the java program stays connected but I do want to deliver too fast since i am displaying some 'realtime' data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `ndataServerReader.ready()`.  Your do/while loop (which should almost certainly just be a while loop) appears to assume that `ndataServerReader.ready()` indicates there's more data to be read, which is not what it's for.

The [Javadoc for Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#ready%28%29) describes the `ready()` method as:

> Tells whether this stream is ready to be read.
>
> Returns: True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input, false
>   otherwise. Note that returning false does not guarantee that the next
>   read will block.

In other worse, `Reader.ready()` will return false if the reader will wait for more data before returning if you attempt to read from it.  This does *not* mean the Reader is done, and in fact you should *expect* this method to return false often when working with a network stream, as it could easily have delays.

Your code currently is likely reading one line (in the `do` block) then checking if the reader is ready (in the `while`), which it probably isn't, and then exiting successfully.  No exceptions are being thrown - you'd see a `SEVERE` level logging message if they were.

Instead of using `ready()`, take advantage of the documented behavior of [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) that says it returns:

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any
>   line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been
>   reached

In other words, simply doing:

```
String ndata = reader.readLine();
while (ndata != null) {
    osw.write(ndata+"\n");
    osw.flush();
    LOG.log(Level.INFO,"Sent");

    ndata reader.readLine();
}
```

Is sufficient to read the whole input stream.

Reference reading: [What's the difference between (reader.ready()) and using a for loop to read through a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325652/whats-the-difference-between-reader-ready-and-using-a-for-loop-to-read-thro)

Comment: thanks this makes much more sense now. If I understand this correctly this also will not really cause a massive CPU usage while waiting.

Comment: It shouldn't, the thread just waits (effectively `Thread.sleep()` in a loop, though the actual implementation is native OS code) until it gets enough data back from the source, or it takes longer than the allowed timeout, which you can set in the Socket object, in which case an exception is thrown indicating not enough data came back.