# Getting process STDOUT - Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, stdout

I made a Mac OS X (native) application that writes one line on STDOUT.

In a Java program, I need to launch that application and get what it writes on the standard output.

The following code works for Windows applications but not for Mac OS X apps.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
result = is.readLine();
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**Edit: The command is `open -W -n MyApp.app --args myargs`**

Comment: The key might be the command. What is it?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623987/java-bufferedreader-works-on-windows-and-not-mac

Comment: the command is `open -W -n MyApp.app --args myargs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it works on Windows honestly. waitFor will wait until the process is done running. At that time stdout from the process does not exist anymore.

You should try switching the waitFor call and the reading of the stream around.

Edit: I don't have a Mac to test that right now but I'm not sure if the `open` command actually outputs stdout of the app. You might have to start the binary inside the .app package directly. Most of the time it's something like `MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp args`

Comment: Actually, for small amounts of output this should work, because the stream is buffered to some extent.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I moved the waitFor call and I launched the app the way you said. Thanks :)